# How to Extend Laravel Model, Collection with New Method?

Tags: php, laravel

I applied some filters for Visitor model in a controller method.

```
$filterRules = array();
array_push($filterRules, ['shop_id', '=', $storeId]);

if ($datePeriod == '0' ) 
{
    // calc all period
} else {
    array_push($filterRules, ['created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes($datePeriod)]);
}

$count = Visitor::where($filterRules)->count();
```

It works OK, but now I have another controller where I need to apply the same filters to the Visitor model and I don't want to duplicate code.

Where is the best place to move this code?

a) Add a new method to the model (Visitor.php)

or

b) Create a helper file

Comment: You can use scopes just [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Elouquent Scopes for this. here is an example

```
public function scopeFilterRules($query, $storeId)
{
    $filterRules = array();
    array_push($filterRules, ['shop_id', '=', $storeId]);

    if ($datePeriod == '0' ) {
        // calc all period
    } else {
        array_push($filterRules, ['created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes($datePeriod)]);
    }

    return $query->where($filterRules);
}
```

Now you can use this anywhere in the application

```
Visitor::filterRules($storeid)->count();
```

For more information

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes